# IE6 position fixed problem

Tags: php, html, css, internet-explorer-6

Ok I am not trying to get an element to a fixed position, im trying to get a div tag out of fixed position. i have a header that is at the top position relative. below it is just another div tag with content in it. when i went to preview it in IE6, the header was positioned at the very top, and was fixed. it stayed at the top when i scrolled down, but really it was position relative. no elements in my css are positioned fixed by the way. has anyone had this before and know a fix?

CSS:

```
#top { height: 168px; 
  display: block; 
  clear: both; 
  overflow: visible; 
  position: relative; 
  margin-bottom: 15px; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="top">
  <a href="link.html">Link 1</a> 
  <a href="link.html">Link 1</a>
  <a href="link.html">Link 1</a> 
  <a href="link.html">Link 1</a> 
</div>
```

then just regular div tag underneath with content...

Comment: You should post your code, or a link to your page.

Comment: Then I would suggest put it online if possible, else just post a snippet of the relevant codes. If you don't put in the effort to help us understand the issue, we can't really do much.

Comment: That would not produce what you're saying. You must be overriding it somewhere you're not seeing. If you inspect the styles in firebug, do you see it being positioned fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait I got it, I added position: relative; to the parent div and then it works now... wierd